# How can I get failed URL from didFailProvisionalNavigation method

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurl, wkwebview

I'm trying to display error message for my web view, and I need to know url which is not available, so I implemented delegate method:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFailProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation withError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.addressBar finishLoadingProgressAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", webView.URL);
    [self showErrorPageForURL:error.userInfo[NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]];
}
```

but NSErrorFailingURLStringKey is deprecated, so how can I get failed URL?
WKNavigation's interface is empty. webView.URL == nil at that moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey` to replace `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey`. If you jump to its definition in Xcode, you will find the below discussion.

> This constant supersedes NSErrorFailingURLStringKey, which was
>   deprecated in Mac OS X 10.6.  Both constants refer to the same value
>   for backward-compatibility, but this symbol name has a better prefix.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 or Swift 4

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    if error._domain == "WebKitErrorDomain" {
        if let info = error._userInfo as? [String: Any] {
            if let url = info["NSErrorFailingURLKey"] as? URL {

            }
            if let urlString = info["NSErrorFailingURLStringKey"] as? String {

            }
        }
    }
}
```